# Is it safe enough to send SSH keys via a file sharing service?

Tags: security, ssh, ssh-keys, mediafire

I need to send an SSH key to other people, is it safe to use a file sharing site like mediafire to upload and share the key?

Comment: You should never send a private key, under any circumstances.

Comment: And public key is safe to share in any way. It's _meant_ to be shared.

Comment: @carminezaccagnino: in this case, copy it on a flash drive and give it to them in person. But whatever you plan do to, there is certainly a better way than sharing the private key.

Comment: @carminezaccagnino: You shouldn't give it to people you trust either.  Instead, you should trust their public keys so they can use their own private keys the way you use yours.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to send it to people I know and trust, and it doesn't give them access to root

You don't need to. Tell them to generate their own key (`ssh-keygen`) and send you the public key. Set the public key to the server and let them connect.